# Declare a variadic template class a friend of a simple template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a first class with a variadic template parameter pack like so:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class A
{
    public: ...etc
```

I have a second class with a simple template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
       public: ...etc
```

The first type arguments to both templates will be the same.

I would like to declare class A a friend of B so that A can access a couple private methods of B. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with unconditional friendship *(i.e. every `A` is a friend of `B`, even if the `T` parameter doesn't match)*, then you can simply use `friend class`:

```
template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class A
{
public:
    void test(B<T>& b);
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
    template <typename, typename...>
    friend class A;

    int priv;
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void A<T, Args...>::test(B<T>& b){ (void) b.priv; }
```

The following code will compile:

```
int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    A<int, float> a;
    a.test(b);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KAMurEKGVHgB8BZf)

Comment: Thanks. The T parameter being the same will be enforced elsewhere, so no biggie about unconditional.